# ngCordova attaching pdf as base64 string to email using emailComposer plugin

Tags: cordova, pdf, cordova-plugins, jspdf, ngcordova

I'm using [jspdf](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) to generate a pdf as a base64 string, all seems to work OK, the format returned is:

```
data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJlbnQgMSAwIFIKL1Jlc291cmNlcyAyIDAgUgovTWVkaWFCb3ggWzAgMCA1OTUuMjggODQxLjg5XQovQ29udGVudHMgNCAwIFIKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwvTGVuZ3RoIDEwPj4Kc3RyZWFtCjAuNTcgdwowIEcKZW5kc3RyZWFtCmVuZG9iagoxIDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUgL1BhZ2VzCi9LaWRzIFszIDAgUiBdCi9Db3VudCAxCj4
```

The [ngCorova docs for email composer](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/emailComposer/) state that attachments can be in the following format:

```
attachments: [
  'base64:icon.png//iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg...',
]
```

Where attachments is an object of the email with properties for 'subject', 'CC', etc.

When my app opens the email client on the device a message pops up saying 'Unable to attach file', everything else works OK (Subject, CC, BCC, etc).

I'm wondering if the format of the base64 pdf is wrong, OR i'm failing to tell the email client the attachment is inline? (not a file), can't find anywhere in the docs that states this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of the string has to be as shown in the example

```
attachments: [
  'base64:icon.png//iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg...',
]
```

for pdf something like `'base64:filename.pdf//' + base64`
without the 'data:application/pdf;base64,'

Comment: That format generates me a corrupt pdf document, any other idea?

Comment: Thanks! Saved me a lot of time :)